# CodeIgniter xmlrpc - Call to a member function ... on a non-object

Tags: codeigniter, xml-rpc

Good day!

I'm using: Codeigniter, xmlrpc library.

I have a problem with client for one api. (http://api.textsale.ru), it's russian )

In api's docs there is function like

```
(array) textsale.GetUser((int)UserId, (string)$hash)
```

I have code

```
$this->xmlrpc->server('http://api.textsale.ru/xmlrpc/', 80);
$this->xmlrpc->method('textsale.getUser');

$request = array(array('UserId'=> array('444***', 'int'),'hash'=>array('435gwrege***', 'string')),'struct');
if ( ! $this->xmlrpc->send_request($request))
{ 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->xmlrpc->display_response());
echo '</pre>';
echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
}
```

And getting

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getVal() on a non-object in <b>***/apiserver1.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />
```

I've tried for $request:

```
$request = array(array( array( ...
$request['UserId'] = ...
```

and so on

If I'm sending for methid witout params -  textsale.GetCategories() - it's ok. I'm getting the Categories list.

So, what should I do to $request ?